# Auto apply coupon in Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Trying to auto apply a coupon code (2 of them actually) when a customer checks out so that I can offer discounts when 4 and 10 items in a specif category or bought, WITHOUT the need for the customer to enter a code.  I have tried adding manually the name of my coupon into the "amount" voucher of the /catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php file without success.  Is there an easy fix for this?

```
        // Gift Voucher
        $data['vouchers'] = array();

        if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
            foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $key => $voucher) {
                $data['vouchers'][] = array(
                    'key'         => $key,
                    'description' => $voucher['description'],
                    'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['FOUR'], $this->session->data['currency']),
```

Comment: Coupons are stored in the `$this->session->data['coupon']` variable.

Comment: Where would that variable be located?